# Fluid simulation fall out of glass?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have created a wine glass in blender, and am working on adding a fluid simulation to the glass (which is my obstacle right now). The problem I am running too is when I try to animate the glass to move from side to side, some of the fluid falls out of the bottom of my glass. I am not sure how this is happening. Some of the fluid does move and splash with my glass, but I can't figure out how or why it continues to drip out the bottom of it. Any ideas!?

Comment: It would help if you add more information about your file. Please add screen shots of your domain settings and the collision objects and other information you consider relevant. Uploading the blend file is the easiest way to find accurate answers. You can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

This may be beause the physics simulation are too rough in comparison to your glass movement speed. You can adjust that by going to Properties Panel -> Scene (3rd icon in the rop row) -> scroll down to "Rigid Body World" -> Increase the values of "Steps per Second" and maybe also "Solver Iterations"

It's also always a good idea to enable "Split Impulse" on that panel.

Comment if this has solved your issue

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to do.

First, increase resolution. At a low resolution, the fluid won't interact with the obstacles in a good way.

Second, your obstacle (the glass) has too much of an impact. Under the obstacle settings, change the impact value to something like 0.5 or lower.